# How to test for Exception in @Async method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-async

How can I assert that a certain exception is thrown inside an `@Async` method?
Because the following exception is caught by Springs `SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

```
@Service
public class Service {
      @Async
      public void run() {
           throw new RuntimeException();
      }
}

public class Test {
   @Test
   public void test() {
        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> service.run()); //this always passes
   }
}
```

Comment: I already know that it is not probably the solution, but a good approach is to defining  two methods, the one with the business logic, and the async wrapper method, and test the one with the business logic

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible for your case, separate testing of asynchronicity and the actual unit of work. E.g. write test that will execute (no 'Async' functionality) Service.run() and assert that no/any/some exceptions are thrown.
In second test (utilizing @Async execution) you could test for the actual unit of work i.e. use your Spring provided bean and test for e.g.:

```
Awaitility.await().atMost(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> runAnyCodeThatChecksTheResultOfYourServiceRunMethod());
```

---

Another method might be to replace the return type of the Service.run() method to java.util.concurrent.Future, Spring will then re-throw the exception. From AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.handleError javadoc:

"If the return type of the method is a {@link Future} object (again, if applicable), the original exception can be propagated by just throwing it at the higher level. However, for all other cases, the exception will not be transmitted back to the client."

Answer (score -1):

```java
import static org.awaitility.Awaitility.await;

Awaitility.await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .untilAsserted(() -> assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () ->  service.run()));
```

Comment: @Tyler2P If you read the code line the key-words are quite enough. `await` `atMost` 5seconds until the RuntimeException is thrown, otherwise the test fails !